# Array At a Variable Index in XSLT

Tags: arrays, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to access a specific element in an array depending on the value of the current date in an XML file.

For example, in the XML

```
<CurrentMonth>5</CurrentMonth>
```

Then, in the XSLT - this is set as a variable as

```
  <xsl:variable name="current-month">
       xsl:value-of select="//CurrentMonth" />
  </xsl:variable>
```

I also have declared an array of the "Month names" as

```
<xsl:variable name="array" as="element()*">
    <Item>Jan</Item>
    <Item>Feb</Item>
    <Item>Mar</Item>
    <Item>Apr</Item>
    <Item>May</Item>
    <Item>Jun</Item>
    <Item>Jul</Item>
    <Item>Aug</Item>
    <Item>Sept</Item>
    <Item>Oct</Item>
    <Item>Nov</Item>
    <Item>Dec</Item>
</xsl:variable>
```

Is it possible in XSLT to return the name of the month (e.g. "Jan") by using a variable as an index for the array?

Example :

```
<xsl:value-of select="$array[$current-month]">
```

The code above is throwing me

```
[FATAL]: Error checking type of the expression 'filter-expr(variable-ref(array/result-tree)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please select either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, not both.

Comment: Apologies, this is XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several syntax errors:

```
<xsl:variable name="current-month">
   xsl:value-of select="//CurrentMonth" />
</xsl:variable>
```

needs to be:

```
<xsl:variable name="current-month">
   <xsl:value-of select="//CurrentMonth" />
</xsl:variable>
```

or preferably:

```
<xsl:variable name="current-month" select="//CurrentMonth" />
```

Next you have:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$array[$current-month]">
```

which needs to be closed:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$array[$current-month]"/>
```

and, in case you are using the first form of defining the variable, it needs to be:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$array[number($current-month)]">
```

Comment: Syntax errors were just in Stack Overflow, as I retyped the scenario and had some mistakes, apologies.

$array[number($current-month)] solved it for me.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Define the variable as `<xsl:variable name="current-month" select="xs:integer(//CurrentMonth)"/>`, then you can use `$array[$current-month]` (although you index a sequence and not an array). With your code you need `$array[position() = $current-month]`.

A minimal but complete stylesheet that runs fine for me with Saxon 9.6.0.7 HE is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:variable name="array" as="element()*">
        <Item>Jan</Item>
        <Item>Feb</Item>
        <Item>Mar</Item>
        <Item>Apr</Item>
        <Item>May</Item>
        <Item>Jun</Item>
        <Item>Jul</Item>
        <Item>Aug</Item>
        <Item>Sept</Item>
        <Item>Oct</Item>
        <Item>Nov</Item>
        <Item>Dec</Item>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="current-month" select="xs:integer(//CurrentMonth)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="$array[$current-month]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and outputs `May` when run against the input `<CurrentMonth>5</CurrentMonth>`.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion and recieved 

[ERROR]: Namespace prefix 'xs' is undeclared.

Comment: Yes, well, you need to also declare `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` on the root of your stylesheet to use the schema data types like `xs:integer`.

Comment: It's now throwing me "[ERROR]: The first argument to the non-static Java function 'integer' is not a valid object reference.
[ERROR]: Could not compile stylesheet
[FATAL]: Error checking type of the expression 'filter-expr(variable-ref(array/result-tree), [pred(variable-ref(current-month/void))])'.
"

Comment: Can you tell us which XSLT 2.0 processor you use? The error messages sound unusual to me.

Comment: @Cdok, I have added a minimal but complete stylesheet that runs fine for me with Saxon 9.6.0.7, I can't reproduce the error you say you get.